# Incomplete file Json

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Why when I add a list of one component does not "[]"?

```
 try {
            json.accumulate("name_channel", txt_channel.getText().toString());
            json.accumulate("channel_date", new Date().toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject idJSON = new JSONObject();
            idJSON.accumulate("id",MainActivity.id_user);
            json.accumulate("list_users", idJSON);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It generates the following:

```
{"name_channel":"xxx","channel_date":"Sat Feb 18 12:00:27 GMT+01:00 2017","list_users":{"id":"1445353654356"}}
```

but I need: **with [ ]**

```
{"name_channel":"xxx","channel_date":"Sat Feb 18 12:00:27 GMT+01:00 2017","list_users":[{"id":"1445353654356"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you will be needed to do something like this

```
JSONObject idJSON = new JSONObject();
idJSON.accumulate("id",MainActivity.id_user);
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put(idJSON);
json.accumulate("list_users", arr);
```